# MySQL union all remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

I want to optimyse my query (not the results) to remove redundant data, make it easy to read and update when I need to.

**Table:**

```
A, B,  C
1  B1  1.99
2  B2  6.99
3  B3  7.99
```

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT A, B FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT A, C FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT A, 'string' FROM TABLE;
```

In this instance A is redundant in my query, as it is written multiple times. How can I make this query to have it only once? Thanks.

EDIT: I want to see EXACTLY the same result but SQL code to refer to column A only once.

Comment: You want to keep only one row that has duplicates values in a single column? If so, which row would you want to keep?

Comment: I should explain this better. I   want to optimise the query. So that actual query contains only one reference to A. I still want the same result as you would get from the query in my example.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide desired results.

Comment: Most probably, your question is not really a MySQL one. You're not talking about database speed but about mentioning "A" in only one place in your code. What language are you using? perhaps you can store "A" in a variable, and then concatenate it as your build your query dynamically.

Comment: am talking about "Column A" as per my example. My whole query refers to this column three times, how can I optimise it, so in the SQL code column A referred only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
SELECT A, B FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT A, C FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT A, 'string' FROM TABLE;
```

Reads from `table` three times.  It actually can be optimized:

```
select A,
       (case when n = 1 then B
             when n = 2 then C
             when n = 3 then 'string'
        end) as B
from TABLE cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n;
```

The SQL engine would normally scan `TABLE` only once for this query, looping through the 3 rows in `n`.  This could be a performance improvement.